# How to install PostgreSQL modules on CentOS[7]

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I  need to install at least 2 ext of postgres DB in my production server: `fuzzystrmatch` and `pg_trgm`
How can I install them on server?

Comment: `yum install postgres-contrib`. Then use `create extension`

Comment: Correct, Thanks for the help :D (Thanks to my genti goes to :D)